# Wait for a specified time java (not Thread.sleep( ))

Tags: java, time, wait

I'm making a simple java game, and I have to make a 3..2..1...Go!
My code is like this:

```
    public void paint321(Graphics g) { // <-- called from paintComponent(Graphics)
    try { 
    int hei = this.getHeight(), wid = this.getWidth();
    g.drawString("3", (int)(wid/2), (int)(hei/2));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    g.drawString("2", (int)(wid/2), (int)(hei/2));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    g.drawString("1", (int)(wid/2), (int)(hei/2));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    g.drawString("Go!", (int)(wid/2)-6, (int)(hei/2));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) { ...
```

But the game GamePanel (my panel extends JPanel and is on a JFrame) looks white for 3 seconds, and then I see "3","2","1" and "Go!" stucked in each other.

I'm not able to use threads, but I think this is because I tell the computer to don't even show the current thread (my GamePanel, I guess).

My question is: how do I wait a specipied time (1 second in my case) without Thread.sleep()?
Or give me an explanation of why I see a white panel

Comment: what do you do after calling this method?

Comment: @Eugene nothing, I close the program after viewing the stucked words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **java.util.Timer** (or **javax.swing.Timer**):

```
 public void paint321(Graphics g) { 
    int hei = this.getHeight(), wid = this.getWidth();

    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         private int counter = 3;

        @Override
        public void run() {               
            if (counter > 0) {
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(counter), wid / 2, hei / 2);
            } else {
                g.drawString("Via!", wid / 2 - 6, hei / 2);
                timer.cancel();
            }

            counter--;
        }
    }, 0L, 1000L);
}
```

Comment: Very complete answer.
Is it more correct to use:
      g.drawString(String.valueOf(counter), wid / 2, hei / 2);
or 
      g.drawString(String.valueOf(counter), (int)(wid / 2), (int)(hei / 2));
? Is cast automatic?

Comment: @maxpesa There are two provided overloads for g.drawString, one for float and one for int

Comment: @AlanFoster Aren't pixel represented as int?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Thread.sleep` you are blocking the JFrame/JPanel from updating, as you have blocked that thread.

For a simple solution you can make use of a Java Timer.

If you are using a game loop mechanic however  - which you most likely will be using if you are making a game. You can simply keep track of the time you started at and drew the initial number, and if 1 second has elapsed since that time, you draw the next number.

Answer (score 0):

You do sleep in your single GUI thread, which prevents it from properly handling various important events. The only viable solution is to go multithreading.

Comment: I'll try to learn about multithreading, but I think it is strange that there are no simple ways of doing this